# App crashes on API Level below 21, which is caused by SQLite classes

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting exception `NoClassDefFoundError` whenever I try to run the app on Android API Level below 21.

```
07-23 03:52:53.410  11681-11681/com.xyz.abc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xyz.abc, PID: 11681
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xyz.abc.database.DB$DBHelper
            at com.xyz.abc.database.DB.<init>(DB.java:27)
            at com.xyz.abc.abcApp.onCreate(abcApp.java:39)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my gradle script

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.abc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'org.lucasr.dspec:dspec:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.telly:mrvector:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'me.tatarka.support:jobscheduler:0.1.1'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'

    compile 'com.marvinlabs:android-floatinglabel-widgets:1.6.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'

    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
}
```

This is my first Android App, I think I've made some silly mistake somewhere. Please help me out

Comment: try restarting eclipse/android studio and running it again.

Comment: @maveroid it didn't help.

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: can i see your full gradle script ?

Comment: Do you have a class declared like this ? `DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` Please share your DB class.

Comment: is DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper. Also is it public static?

Comment: @Beyka Its private static inner class

Comment: @Sree Updated my question

Comment: are you defining content provider?

Comment: As I know dbhelper should be public class, because system use it to create and update sql db. Just try to change it to public static.

Comment: I suspect there's something wrong in the way you use your private class or how it is declared. EDIT : it should probably be declared public, but that shouldn't throw a NoClassDefFoundError I think

Comment: your dbhelper is under the package com.xyz.abc for sure?  and can you post code releated to how you are invoking it.

Comment: I made it public static, still no use. It works fine on API level 21, and gives exception in all lower level of API.

Comment: Can you print code for your DB class that contains DBHelper?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with Android version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the real problem. It was the issue with multidex. Android SDK Build Tools 21.1 and higher supports multidex as part of your build configuration so it was running smoothly on 21 and above devices.

I had to add `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0` library and make some code changes to ensure that app runs on lower versions without any hurdle.

For detailed information visit https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html